# Validation message shows, but still saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Really weird, but I made a custom validation in my model. When multiple validations are triggered, the form is not saving and the custom validation error show in the form.

However....

When the custom validation is the only validation that is triggered, the form saves incl. the data that is invalid?

extra_guest model

```
 validate :no_dates_overlap

  def no_dates_overlap
    ranges = [] # cache proccessed date ranges

    # iterate over all extra_guest_prices
    extra_guest_prices.each do |egp|
      if ranges.any? { |rng| rng.include?(egp.start_date) || rng.include?(egp.end_date) }
        # if a previous range includes this dates, add the error and break the loop
        egp.errors.add(:start_date, "Dates overlap")
        break
      else
        # else, cache it and check the next
        ranges << (egp.start_date..egp.end_date)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: try return errors.add :base, "Dates overlap"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From rails [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods)

> The valid? method will verify that the errors collection is empty, so
>   your custom validation methods should add errors to it when you wish
>   validation to fail

You need to add error to record's errors array. So change your code as below:

```
errors.add(:start_date, "Dates overlap")
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot add errors in extra_guest_prices. You should add the error in extra_guest.

Try:
`self.errors.add(:base, "Dates overlap")`